# Why can't I slide the ListView.builder on Flutter WEB?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I try to slide the ListView.Builder on my browser (chrome), it doesn't work...
What's messed up is that when I run the devtools of chrome and activate the device toolbar in 'Responsive mode' it works... It seems that Flutter only accepts simulated touch screens...
Any ideas?

```
         Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    width: 100.h,
    height: 100.w,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        colors: 
        [
          Color(0xFF3366FF),
          Color(0xFF00CCFF),
        ],
        begin: FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
        end: FractionalOffset(0.0, 1.0),
        stops: [0.0, 1.0],
        tileMode: TileMode.clamp
      ),
    ),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        TopBar(),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.w),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                 icon: Icon(
                   Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                   color: Colors.white,
                   size: 8.sp,
                 )
              ),
              Text(
                "En attente de validation",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 8.sp
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1.h),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text(
              "Prospection 'maison'",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 8.sp
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        //normal
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1.w),
            child: ListView.builder(
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1.h),
                  child: 
                  
                  //Card Building
                  Container(
                    width: 20.h,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.h),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text(
                              "22",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Basic',
                                fontSize: 15.sp
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1.h),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text(
                              "JUMP STREET",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Basic',
                                fontSize: 9.sp
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.w),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Icon(
                              CupertinoIcons.building_2_fill,
                              size: 40.sp,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1.h),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text(
                              "a",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Basic',
                                fontSize: 9.sp
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.w),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 15.h,
                            child: CupertinoButton(
                              color: Colors.green,
                              child: Text("Completer"),
                              onPressed: () {

                              }
                            ),
                          ),
                        )

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),



                );
              },
              itemCount: 30,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        //multi
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1.h),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text(
              "Prospection 'immeuble'",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 8.sp
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 1.w),
            child: ListView.builder(
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1.h),
                  child: 
                  
                  //Card Building
                  Container(
                    width: 20.h,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.h),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text(
                              "22",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Basic',
                                fontSize: 15.sp
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1.h),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text(
                              "JUMP STREET",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Basic',
                                fontSize: 9.sp
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.w),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Icon(
                              CupertinoIcons.building_2_fill,
                              size: 40.sp,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1.h),
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text(
                              "b",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Basic',
                                fontSize: 9.sp
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.w),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 15.h,
                            child: CupertinoButton(
                              color: Colors.green,
                              child: Text("Completer"),
                              onPressed: () {

                              }
                            ),
                          ),
                        )

                      ],
                    ),
                  ),



                );
              },
              itemCount: 30,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ]
    ),
  ),
);
```

This is my flutter doctor.

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 2.5.0-2.0.pre.113, on Microsoft Windows [version 
10.0.19043.1110], locale fr-FR)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
   X cmdline-tools component is missing
     Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
     See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
   X Android license status unknown.
     Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
     See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more 
     details.
   [√] Chrome - develop for the web
   [√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.8.3)
   [√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
   [√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.1)
   [√] VS Code (version 1.58.2)
   [√] Connected device (3 available)
```

Comment: Scrolling works fine on web, using either mouse scroll wheel, or mouse drag, or fingers if you're running it on tablet or phone but in a browser. Are you sure you want scroll to be horizontally? And what is inside your column in the code you posted?

Comment: I added the full code, still dont know why it dont work..

Comment: do `flutter clean` and run again.

Comment: already done...

Answer (score 0):

try to modify the listview parameter to :

```
        child: ListView.builder(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
```